# Alternative way to print Arabic text in qt

Tags: c++, qt, api, printing, arabic

I'm trying to print an HTML web page that contains Arabic text in Qt. Everything prints fine, but the Arabic text doesn't print properly.

First I tried this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>
#include <QString>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebPage>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebFrame>


QString htmlItem(QString Item)
{
    QString r="";
    r.append( "<td>"
               "<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:'Tahoma'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">");
    r.append(Item);
     r.append("</span></p></td>");
    return r;
}

QString htmlRow(QString MFC,QString MFT,QString D,QString N)
{
    QString ret ="" ;
    ret.append("<tr>");

    ret.append(htmlItem(MFC));
    ret.append(htmlItem(MFT));
    ret.append(htmlItem(D));
    ret.append(htmlItem(N));
   ret.append("</tr>");
    return ret;
}

QString htmlTable(QString rows)
{
    QString ret = "";
    ret.append("<table border=\"1\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;\" align=\"center\" width=\"90%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"4\">"
            "<tbody>");
    ret.append(rows);
    ret.append("</tbody></table>");
    return ret ;
}
QString htmlClientName(QString name)
{
    QString retu="<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\""
            "font-family:&#39;Tahoma&#39;; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\">";
    retu.append(name);
    retu.append("</span></p>");
    return  retu;
}

QString htmlClientPage(QString Table,QString Name)
{
    QString r = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">"
            "<!-- saved from url=(0045)file:///C:/Users/MG/Desktop/Untitled%201.html "
            "-->"
            "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\"><title>QTextEdit Example</title><style "
            "type=\"text/css\">"
            "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }"
            "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:&#39;MS Shell Dlg 2&#39;; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-"
            "style:normal;\"";
    r.append(htmlClientName(Name));
    r.append(htmlTable(Table));
    r.append("</body></html>");
    return r;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString cD="";
    cD.append(htmlRow("m","n","b","v"));
    cD.append(htmlRow("hgfh","n","b","gggg"));
    cD.append(htmlRow("m","vvvv","bbbbbbb","v"));
    cD.append(htmlRow("m","ssssss","b","sssssssss"));
    QString data = htmlClientPage(htmlTable(cD), "???? ???? ");
    ui->textEdit->setText(data);


#if !defined(QT_NO_PRINTER) && !defined(QT_NO_PRINTDIALOG)
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QPrintDialog *dlg = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);
    if (ui->textEdit->textCursor().hasSelection())
        dlg->addEnabledOption(QAbstractPrintDialog::PrintSelection);



    dlg->setWindowTitle(tr("Print Document"));
    if (dlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
        ui->textEdit->print(&printer);
    delete dlg;
#endif

}
```

The output printed file was like this:

[image]

I searched for how to solve this problem and ended up with sum bugs in Qt when printing Arabic text. And I tried some other Qwidgets like QwebView and QwebPage and ended up with more problems.

Now I'm asking if there is an alternative way to use Qt printing like **Windows API or something else** to solve this problem.

I use
SDK : Qt 5.2.1 with Qt Creator 3.0.1
Operating System : Microsoft Windows 8

Edit: I need to mention that Qt prints Arabic text to PDF well.

Edit: I'm pretty sure that the **problem is not the encoding**. I searched for this problem and I found these bugs in Qt:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-4452?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel

**I think the problem is related to this one.**

Comment: Why do you do `fromLocal8Bit`? You obviously need unicode.

Comment: I tried it also and the problem is still there..the page is shown well in the QtextEdit (not very well) but when i try to print it, it doesn't look proper.

Comment: And what does the HTML header say about the encoding?

Comment: charset=UTF-8  is that what you mean ? i'm not very good in html

Comment: Yes, and what is the declaration of `htmlArabicPage`?

Comment: Qstring htmlArabicPage =  htmlClientPage(htmlTable(cD),"محمد جمال "); where htmlClientPage() function returns Qstring.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 QString str = QString::fromLocal8Bit(data.toLocal8Bit());
```

doesn't make sense to me. I am not sure if it will work, but try the following:

```
 ui->textEdit->setText(htmlArabicPage);
```

and tell me what happens.

Also if you have this:

```
 htmlClientPage(htmlTable(cD),"محمد جمال ");
```

in your **source** code, you should be very careful. If you want to create a Unicode literal in C++11 then you should do:

```
 u8"محمد جمال "
```

where the text is encoded in **UTF-8**.

Otherwise, you should try if "محمد جمال " is being interpreted well. Try this:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("محمد جمال ");
    qDebug() << QString::fromLocal8Bit("محمد جمال ");
    return 0;
}
```

The bug you posted is from the previous version of Qt and it has been closed.

Comment: The same output.. I tried a lot of things with QtextEdit  and  QWebView and other Qwidgets but nothing helps.See the last Edit in the question :)

Comment: i Edited the question to show the whole code after modifying it as you suggested. however i got this error while trying to use u8 : error: 'u8' was not declared in this scope
             QString data = htmlClientPage(htmlTable(cD), u8"ظ…ط­ظ…ط¯ ط¬ظ…ط§ظ„ ");

Comment: @Eng.MG the `u8` literal is available in C++11. Check if your compiler is set to enable the C++11 features.

Comment: qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("محمد جمال "); this worked fine.